# Max along a row when there are more than one max

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

How do i find all the indices which are the maximum along a given row of a matrix.
max(a(1,:)) returns only the first maximum!

I want all the indices of all the elements which are maximum (multiple)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` returns the value of the maximum element, which you can then `find` in the array:

```
ind = find(a(1, :) == max(a(1, :)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The following solution applies the operation to the entire matrix at once preventing the need for any looping.

You can compute the max row each row and then use `eq` (`==`) to **compare each value in each row to it's row-wise maximum**.

```
a(row, :) == max(a(row, :))
```

For speed we can wrap this in a call to `bsxfun`.

```
a = [1 2 2; 4 4 3];
out = bsxfun(@eq, a, max(a, [], 2))

%   0     1     1
%   1     1     0
```

This yields a logical matrix where the 1's indicate that it was a maximum for that given row. If you want the indices, you could apply `find` to this to get the row and columns.

```
[rows, cols] = find(out)
```

And you could use `accumarray` to group them by row if needed

```
accumarray(row, col, [], @(x){x})

%   out{1} =
%    
%        2
%        3
%    
%   out{2} =
%    
%        1
%        2
```

Comment: Much faster than the `find` solutions. By far the best.

Comment: Thanks, i suppose it is faster but i have accepted the simpler answer. I will upvote your answer as it might help someone looking for speed

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan You're welcome to select an inferior answer, but at least accept Mad Physicist's who posted well before the one you selected. Also if you actually read my post I mention the simple approach. I have highlighted to indicate where.

Comment: @Suever. FWIW, I think your answer is much more definitive than mine.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well professors probably start asking questions when you turn in an assignment using `bsxfun` and you can't explain what it does :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is as simple as

```
row = aMatrix(rowNumber, :)
find(row==max(row))
```

which obviously condenses into

```
find(aMatrix(rowNumber, :)==max(aMatrix(rowNumber, :)))
```

The first way runs without extracting the same row twice (which looks alot nicer in my opinion), the second way writes fewer variables.